# ERROR: Write preference and partitioning field are not supported with DDL/DML statements

Tags: google-bigquery, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I'm trying to schedule a table in BigQuery using this query

```
DECLARE isEmpty DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(keyword) = 0 from dataset.check_table);

DECLARE isFilled DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(keyword) > 0 from dataset.check_table);

IF isEmpty
  THEN SELECT * FROM dataset.table_a;

ELSEIF isFilled
  THEN SELECT * FROM dataset.table_b;

END IF;
```

Turns out that the scheduling didn't work and gave me"

`ERROR: Write preference and partitioning field are not supported with DDL/DML statements`

Then, I try a workaround to make a that query as a view using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dataset.v_table AS

DECLARE isEmpty DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(keyword) = 0 from dataset.check_table);

DECLARE isFilled DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(keyword) > 0 from dataset.check_table);

IF isEmpty
  THEN SELECT * FROM dataset.table_a;

ELSEIF isFilled
  THEN SELECT * FROM dataset.table_b;

END IF;
```

But I couldn't do it since it's giving me another error:

`Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword SELECT or keyword WITH but got keyword DECLARE at [3:1]`

Does anyone here have any idea so that I could do the scheduling?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using scheduled queries? How are you setting it? Are you using a table as the query destination?

Comment: @rmesteves hey. Yes. I'm using scheduled queries, I appended the result of that query above to one of my other table.

Comment: It seems that view creation in the console doesnt support DECLARE statements. As you can see here, a query statement doesn't encompasses this kind of statement https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax

Comment: Can you explain exactly what are you trying to do?

Comment: Okay, let me explain what I'm trying to do here. 

Let's say I have this dataset.final_table that I want to update daily using THAT scheduled query.

Why do I use declare statement? I only want to run the query when one of the source of the query is empty as I asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61226775/if-conditional-to-run-schedule-query?noredirect=1#comment108558935_61226775

Is this clear enough?

Comment: Are you trying to set a destination table in scheduled query? As I said in this same post, at the moment you can not set a destination table in a scheduled query if you use scripting (declare, set, and other expressions)

Comment: Try using the query I provided as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  UNNEST( 
    (SELECT
      (
        CASE (SELECT COUNT(keyword)  from dataset.check_table) = 0
        WHEN TRUE 
        THEN ( 
             SELECT ARRAY( 
                           SELECT AS STRUCT *
                           FROM dataset.table_a)
        )
        ELSE (SELECT ARRAY( 
                           SELECT AS STRUCT *
                           FROM dataset.table_b)
        )
        END
      )
   )
)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for giving me this workaround, but using this query, even though the check_table is empty, it cost me the same amount of billing as when the check_table is not empty. Hence, it'd be as simple as I run SELECT * FROM dataset.table_b without using this CASE WHEN conditional.

Comment: @IrenRamadhan what do you mean? This query will do basically the same that the other one you were trying to use. In both this query and yours,  SELECT COUNT(keyword)  from dataset.check_table will be run, and depending on the result, the query A or the query B will be run

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response. Sorry I didn't explain enough about this. So, the table_a is an empty table, hence when the first condition met, I will run the table_a which cost me 0, and if the second one applied, I will have the cost accordingly. However, using your query cost as much as the second one would cost me even when the condition that's met is the first one. Let me know if this is not clear enough.